# Symfony: Logout in KernelEvents::CONTROLLER Listener

Tags: symfony

Is there a possibility to logout user in `KernelEvents::CONTROLLER` Listener?
If yes, how?

In this Listener I get some data from database and put it into a service. But if the query returns no data, I would like to add a flash message and logout user.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple route for logout and configure it under security prarameters ([take a look](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/security.html#logging-out)).
But if you insiste it depend in what you want to build. You can create an event subscriber to `kernel.controller` event.

As mentionned  [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html#tag-controllers-to-be-checked) `kernel.controller` (aka KernelEvents::CONTROLLER) listener gets notified on every request, right before the controller is executed. So, first, you need some way to identify if the controller that matches the request needs.

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
...
    class LogoutSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var SecurityContext
         */
        private $securityContext;

        public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext)
        {
            $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        }

        public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
        {
            $controller = $event->getController();

            if (!is_array($controller)) {
                return;
            }

            if ($controller[0] instanceof YourController) {
                 //Log out only if this method returns false
                 $s = $this->someService->init();
                if(false === $s) {
                    //Then logout here
                    //Pass parameters to the controller
                    //which has logout method to invalidate session
                    //null the token and add Flash message
                    $controller = new SecurityController();
                    $controller->setRouter($this->router);
                    $controller->setSession($this->session);
                    $controller->setTokenStorage($this->tokenStorage);
                    $controller->setTranslator($this->translator);
                    $replacementController = array($controller, 'logout');
                    $event->setController($replacementController);
                }
            }
        }

        public static function getSubscribedEvents()
        {
            return array(
                KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => 'onKernelController',
            );
        }
    }
```

If you want more then logout, just inject the appropriate dependency and use it, for example for flash messages, inject `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session` tagged with `session`
and then just call `$this->session->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'You have been successfully been logged out.');`

Comment: This solution is not working. I have already tried it. The token is set to null, session is invalidated but the Symfony continues to invoke the Controller. But I have changed it in a way that I just set controller to the Logout controller. Thank you.

Comment: Symfony continues to invoke the Controller ?? how and how did you fix it, Could you just rpopose an deit to my solution ?

Comment: I don't know how but it did. Controller was invoked. Of course when I refreshed I was redirected to login page but the redirect should be done right away. I have fixed this like on edit of your proposal.

Comment: Ok happy for you, any way i acceppted your edit, wish you think it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution. Thank you. Cheers!